# Transfered data from activity is always null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get data from one activity in other. But data always null.

```
    val res = Intent()
    res.putExtra("uri", imageUri)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, res)
    finish()
```

In the second activity I always get data as null. What is the problem? (`imageUri` is not null when I put it).

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
     //data == null, WHY???

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the intent with the current context and target class.

```
val intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity,ProfileActivity::class.java) // define you activity in which you want to go
intent.putExtra("Username","John Doe")
startActivity(intent)
```